# Spring webflux security all permitted endpoints return 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a problem with the configuration of spring boot. 
I loaded following starter projects

`compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')`

and my security config is following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/actuator/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .build();

}
```

but whenever I try to go to an actuator endpoint I get a 404
Whenever the application starts I get following mappings for actuator

`2018-08-24 17:15:28.835  INFO 60807 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-08-24 17:15:28.846  INFO 60807 --- [  restartedMain] .b.a.e.w.r.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public org.reactivestreams.Publisher<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.reactive.AbstractWebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping$ReadOperationHandler.handle(org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange)
2018-08-24 17:15:28.847  INFO 60807 --- [  restartedMain] .b.a.e.w.r.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}"
2018-08-24 17:15:28.847  INFO 60807 --- [  restartedMain] .b.a.e.w.r.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}"`

and when I try to go to an endpoint I get:

`2018-08-24 17:24:31.400  WARN 60846 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8080/actuator/health]: Response status 404`

What am I missing here?
Thx for helping out!

Comment: Do you really have `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` as a dependency? This one brings `spring-boot-starter-web` and should make your app a Spring MVC app. The logs are saying otherwise, so could you please clarify that? Could you paste as well you `application.properties` and env properties?

Comment: I made a mistake in a filter I made, but it happened right after I included hateoas and actuator, removed hateoas since I don't really need it (copy - paste from another project), anyway I'm still learning stupid mistake but you learn from it ;)

Comment: Is it fixed then? If so, you can answer your own question. Thanks!